# first python program doesn't look right

Tags: python

This is my first python program, i've been reading about python for awhile and the program works but I don't think I did everything correctly. here's the code

```
dict_top = {'a':[0], 'b':[0], 'c':[0], 'd':[0], 'e':[0], 'f':[0], 'g':[0],
            'h':[0], 'i':[0], 'j':[0], 'k':[0], 'l':[0], 'm':[0], 'n':[0],
            'o':[0], 'p':[0], 'q':[0], 'r':[0], 's':[0], 't':[0], 'u':[0],
            'v':[0], 'w':[0], 'x':[0], 'y':[0], 'z':[0]}

with open('planet-names.txt') as file_object: # this will automatically close
    for planet_name in file_object:
        for letter in planet_name:
            if letter in dict_top:
                a = dict_top[letter][0]
                dict_top[letter][0] = a + 1
                dict_top[letter].append(planet_name.find(letter))

print(dict_top)
```

`planet-names.txt` is just the name of a planet on each line
I want to count the times A, B, C happen in each name of a bunch of planets
and also record the different positions they were found at.

This is not homework! i'm trying to make a program that generates names of planets randomly!!!

How are you supposed to code stuff like dict_top? that took me like an hour to type all that

Comment: What print out do you get? And what print out did you expect? What's the content of `planet-names.txt`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `collections.Counter`

```
import collections
c = collections.Counter()
with open('planet-names.txt') as file_object: # this will automatically close
    for planet_name in file_object:
        c.update(collections.Counter(planet_name))

print c
```

or you can create the dict using `dict.fromkeys`

```
import string
dict_top = dict.fromkeys(list(string.ascii_lowercase),[0])
```

Comment: I got the output that I wanted but the program didn't look right at all, I knew I didn't do it right

Answer (score 2):

Suppose Your file containe names 'earth', 'jupitor', 'saturn', 'pluto'

```
dict_top = {'a':[0], 'b':[0], 'c':[0], 'd':[0], 'e':[0], 'f':[0], 'g':[0], 'h':[0], 'i':[0], 'j':[0], 'k':[0], 'l':[0], 'm':[0], 'n':[0], 'o':[0], 'p':[0], 'q':[0], 'r':[0], 's':[0], 't':[0], 'u':[0], 'v':[0], 'w':[0], 'x':[0], 'y':[0], 'z':[0]}
```

---

```
with open('planet-names.txt') as file_object:
    for planet_name in file_object.readlines():
        for letter in planet_name:
            if letter in dict_top:
                dict_top[letter][0] += 1

print(dict_top)
```

This will returns count like:

```
{'a': [2],
 'b': [0],
 'c': [0],
 'd': [0],
 'e': [1],
 'f': [0],
 'g': [0],
 'h': [1],
 'i': [1],
 'j': [1],
 'k': [0],
 'l': [1],
 'm': [0],
 'n': [1],
 'o': [2],
 'p': [2],
 'q': [0],
 'r': [3],
 's': [1],
 't': [4],
 'u': [3],
 'v': [0],
 'w': [0],
 'x': [0],
 'y': [0],
 'z': [0]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to define dict top in some smart way? If yes then use

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
dict_top = {}
for char in ascii_lowercase:
    dict_top[char] = [0]
```

Comment: python 2.7 introduces dictionary comprehensions `dict_top = {char:[0] for char in ascii_lowercase}` but good answer for a beginner I suppose

Comment: Yes, just wanted to add this way) Actually I believe there are too many ways to define this dict in 1-2 lines of cide

Comment: Yea that is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Use fromkeys:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
dict_top=dict.fromkeys(list(ascii_lowercase,[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Python !

"list comprehension" (or dict comprehension in this case) is one thing you'll love:

```
dict_top = {k:[0] for k in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"}
```

However I'd write it (without thinking to much) differently, as I guess the letters that do not appear in any name are useless :

```
dict_top = {} 
with open('planet-names.txt') as file_object: 
    for planet_name in file_object:
        for i,letter in enumerate(planet_name):
            try:
                dict_top[letter][0] +=1
                dict_top[letter].append(i)
            except KeyError:
                dict_top[letter]=[1,i]
```

about "enumerate" check https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html

Have fun !